# If the Earth is curved, why don't planes need to adjust attitude to stay parallel to the ground?

Tags: aircraft

If I'm flying parallel to the ground and I never adjust my attitude, shouldn't my altitude above the ground start rising if the Earth is curving away from me? In practice, why doesn't this happen.

**Edit: Follow up question to the answers already given.**

Most have suggested that the plane's course is indeed corrected. If we ignore the fact that the atmosphere is not uniform, would it be possible to have the lift cancel out the gravitational force just enough that the conditions for circular motion are met i.e.

$$F_g-F_l=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$?

Comment: Engines develop a kind of _tangential acceleration_ to maintain flight. Because air phenomenons ( resistance, etc ) and to reach the targeted speed, the _tangential acceleration_ must have more than 90° with gravity ( then it's not exactly tangential ). A very smooth process, there is anything like manual adjustment just because Earth is curved.

Comment: If you are flying parallel to the ground, you are automatically staying at the same altitude because the ground is curved the same way as the atmosphere. You wouldn't be flying on a straight line, of course. If you were attempting to fly a straight line you would either soon run into the max. altitude at which your plane can develop lift or you would crash into the ground. In practice you are probably flying a plane that is aerodynamically stable, i.e. without control inputs and changes to the engine thrust the plane will stay leveled at on altitude, anyway.

Comment: In other words, who says they _don't_ adjust their attitude?  Normally, either the pilot's hands, or the autopilot will be continually adjusting all of the plane's controls to maintain straight and level flight.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp , the airplane has a control system on it known as an autopilot, which manipulates the control surfaces in order to maintain a constant altitude above the ground.  A human pilot would do the same thing.  Even if this weren't the case, there is a POWERFUL need to do this, because aircraft traveling north/south are assigned a different altitude than aircraft traveling east/west.  This minimizes the chance of collision between aircraft, so it is a VERY DESIRABLE thing to do.

Comment: Re *most have suggested that the plane's course is indeed corrected.* Most of the people here are neither pilots nor aerospace engineers. You asked this question at the wrong part of the SE network. This question is based on the mistaken assumption that "straight and level flight" means going in a Euclidean straight line.

Comment: according to you, without an action of the pilot to restore the altitude due specifically to the earth curve, the plane will go to orbit ? notice that the vector gravity changes all the way around. _Perhaps_ merely gravity does the main work ... A comparison with a body in orbit would be usefull, the difference being the acceleration related to buoyancy

Answer (score 3):

I am a student pilot. I've got 100 hours and 300 landings.

Throw a paper airplane. Does it fly in a straight line? Of course not.
Neither does a big plane.

It only follows the course, horizontally and vertically, that the pilot controls it to fly.
The way it turns from one heading to another is by temporarily banking to one side, exactly like a bicycle.
The way it changes altitude above the ground is by using more or less power.
The way it changes speed is by using more or less elevator trim.

All of these things are monitored by the pilot and adjusted as needed.
If they are not adjusted, the plane flies at a constant speed, on a constant heading, at a constant rate of climb or descent above the earth.

Take a flying lesson. It doesn't cost much and is a great experience.

Comment: Re *If they are not adjusted, the plane flies at a constant speed, on a constant heading, at a constant rate of climb or descent above the earth.* One word: Phugoid.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yeah, sure. Good planes, properly loaded, damp that out. (I'm talking about common aircraft. Aerobatics and fighters are a different story.)

Comment: I used to fly. Had a near crash experience which made me "oh shit" my way out of that hobby. 

I don't understand the paper plane analogy as the paper plane is not powered. My question was more regarding, what happens if you put a plane on a course parallel to the ground radially below it and just leave it, assuming a uniform atmosphere and all those other "physics problem" assumptions you have to make.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp: So you should know what I mean, having had your hands on the controls yourself. Aircraft power is not on/off, if it more/less. Aircraft are always gliding. Whether they glide down or glide up is just a matter of whether the thrust is less than the drag or more. If you want the plane to maintain constant height above the earth, that's one power setting. If you want it to follow a "straight line" and ascend, that takes a higher power setting. If you want to descend to the airport, you decrease the power, to idle if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no pilot, but I believe that airplanes typically (whether on autopilot or not) maintain a constant altitude when cruising, i.e. height above the ground, using an altimeter. So if the plane (via computer or human operator) detects the altitude is increasing, the plane uses its control surfaces to alter its ascent rate and go back to the desired altitude.

This results in following the curve of the Earth without the need for worrying about whether or not the plane is traveling in a "straight line".

A little geometry leads me to calculate that a 747 at cruising speeds that was intentionally flying in a straight line would ascend about $1.7 ~\rm ft$ in $1 ~\rm sec$, and the plane's nose would be $0.002°$ above the horizon. Now, that ascent rate would increase nonlinearly if the plane continues in that direction, but presumably the pilot or autopilot would be continuously adjusting the plane's attitude, so the ascent rate would never get much higher than that.

Comment: Why is it, then, that I can stand on the Earth and go in a circle without ever needing to make any corrections?

Comment: @Dargscisyhp Not sure exactly what you're asking. Are you imagining standing on the ground and walking in a little circle? Or walking around the Earth? What do you mean by "corrections"? Walking on the ground is a little different from flying in a plane - when you're walking, your altitude is primarily determined by where the ground is.

Comment: I just mean, the Earth is spinning, right. I'm obviously spinning with it. But I make no course corrections to do this. Gravity keeps me on Earth. Why isn't this the same thing for the plane?

Comment: Ah, I see. When you're walking around on the ground, the normal force from the ground constantly maintains your vertical equilibrium by balancing out the force of gravity. You don't need to actively control your altitude, because the ground controls it for you "automatically". The same is not true for a plane - a plane has to actively control its altitude. Yes, it is under the influence of gravity, but a plane can arbitrarily adjust the opposing lift force that its wings generate. So the question presumes correctly that the plane can freely choose its flight path.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp, every step you take is a "correction".

Comment: Hmm, or is it the case that the plane fly's just so the gravitational force - the lift give you the conditions for circular motion, i.e. 

$$F_g-F_l=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$

Comment: @Dargscisyhp I mean, yes, effectively, on average, that is the case while the airplane is maintaining altitude, but I don't think the airplane maintains its course by carefully measuring and regulating the lift force. The difference between $F_g$ and $F_l$ in that expression is about 0.1% of the total lift force necessary, and I doubt the plane's ability to regulate or even measure its own lift force is nearly that accurate. In practice, maintaining altitude with an altimeter is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm flying parallel to the ground and I never adjust my attitude, shouldn't my altitude above the ground start rising if the Earth is curving away from me?

This question, and most of the responses and comments to it, are based on a misunderstanding of what "straight and level flight" means. It does not mean flying in a Euclidean straight line at a constant speed. The concept of flying a Euclidean straight line doesn't make any sense when it comes to an aircraft flying through the atmosphere of a more or less spherical planet. "Straight and level" instead means flying with zero bank, zero roll, and a constant speed, constant altitude, and constant pitch angle.

The pitch angle of an aircraft is measured with respect to local vertical / local horizontal (LVLH). This means that from the perspective of an inertial observer, an aircraft in straight and level flight is constantly pitching down. The only people to whom this is a concern are the designers of an aircraft that uses an Inertial Navigation System. Even then, the first thing the designers of such a system will do is to transform the inertial attitude and attitude rate into quantities more amenable to a human pilot or to an automated control system. Those more amenable quantities include attitude and attitude rate with respect to LVLH.

An LVLH frame (e.g., north-east-down or east-north-up) is a rotating frame. There are applications where an inertial frame is less useful than is a rotating frame. Flying an aircraft is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The answers I've seen above accept your premise: the plane would indeed fly off-Earth if it was "dumb" (i.e. altitude not controlled by human or software). This is not the case.

This is my attempt to explain as simply as you are reasoning:

Assume a "dumb" plane flights straight, parallel to the current position. Nothing turbines pumping and there is no way to change altitude (all flaps fixed). This airplane would not escape the Earth, why?

First if the turbines work worse as air rarifies at high altitudes, and at some point lose "traction" and fall. Secondly, the levitating force on the wings depends on the air density and the plane relative speed to the air, so even if the "traction" effect is low, the air support will be lower and at some point will not be sustained. Thirdly, as it escapes horizontally the angle of vertical becomes that of the flight direction, or as was mentioned, it will behave as if you suddenly start flying up, which will eliminate air support on the wings and fall.

So in summary, even a "dumb" plane will not escape horizontally because is much like a boat in the ocean: its stays on floating altitude rather than falling out of the horizon. It depends on the medium to perform, it is propelled by the medium (even turbine planes) and is supported by the medium.

BTW, that is also why we cannot use turbines to fly rockets up to vacuum space.

Comment: My contention wasn't that it would escape Earth, my contention was that if it flies an infinitesimal distance parallel to the ground radially below it there should be an infinitesimal increase in height as well. I'm aware that it will not continue unabated because the atmosphere thins out and so on, but I as wondering why it is, even after flying hundreds of miles, we never notice a change in height.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood. The other answers cover the technological ways to ways keep accurate altitude. Older pilots had to know well to use readings of altitude and windspeed to stay in correct path.

Comment: according to the question as asked , it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, this is exactly what would happen if you were to fly in a straight line.

This is why planes don't fly in a straight line: they adjust their path to stay at the same altitude.

Comment: This is something I never learned while I was piloting. The adjustment amount must be extremely small.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp, OK, so picture yourself flying straight and level, 2000 feet above the ground.  When your only references are the horizon out beyond your windscreen, and the seat of your pants, how could you expect to tell whether you were following a downward curve around the Earth or following a truly straight line?

Comment: Afterthought:  I guess I'm saying that the adjustment amount _will_ be extremely small.  It amounts to approximately one degree of rotation for every seventy miles of your ground track.  At the speed of a commercial airliner, that's going to be on the order of 0.1 degrees per minute.  Even if that was not totally lost in the noise of routine attitude adjustments, I doubt that your inner ear would be sensitive enough to notice.

Comment: it's not an adjustement, it is the way a plane flies on a real plane ground. For the Earth curvature , the work is done by gravity

Comment: @Dargscisyhp - This is something you never learned because you didn't need to learn it. It's implicit in how aircraft fly and in how the navigation sensors on an aircraft work. The 8-ball / attitude indicator / artificial horizon  shows you the aircraft's attitude with respect to local vertical / local horizontal. This is a rotating frame of reference. You as the pilot don't need to be concerned with this. Using these rotating frame sensors help prevent the pilot from mistakenly flying a Euclidean straight line. If you tried to do that, the plane would soon enter pilot-induced oscillations.